SQLDelight - how to specify returning type for queries?
I've been playing with SQLDelight for a few days, and after initial delightment I've stumbled upon a mystery - how to define query returning types?
For example, if I have a table
CREATE TABLE LocationEntity (id INTEGER, name TEXT NOT NULL, description TEXT);

If I do
getAll:
    SELECT * FROM LocationEntity

SqlDelight will return a list of LocationEntity objects, which is great.
But if I have projection select, like this:
getAll:
    SELECT id, name FROM LocationEntity

SQLDelight generates a new type GetAll. How can I tell it to use my object ShortLocation(id: Long, name: String) instead?
What am I missing here?
Can it even be done, or I am stuck with many generated types (for almost every query)?

One way to do this is to define ShortLocation as a VIEW in your SQL
CREATE VIEW ShortLocation AS
SELECT id, name FROM LocationEntity

Then your query can be
getAll:
SELECT * FROM ShortLocation

